# OLSR Routing Protocol

Tags: routes

where to get **OLSR** source code(or patch) for **Glomosim** and how to use that. For my research process, i want the OLSR as baseline. I found that on Niigata's site http://www2.net.ie.niigata-u.ac.jp/olsr-e.php, but don't know how to use that. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Glomosim appears to be commercialized, the source code is not readily available.  Wikipedia links many implementations from its [OLSR page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimized_Link_State_Routing_Protocol).  See [olsr.org](http://www.olsr.org/) and [nrl](http://cs.itd.nrl.navy.mil/work/olsr/index.php).  Also, the free simulation tool ns3 has many ad-hoc protocols including OLSR and is [free to download](http://www.nsnam.org/releases/) (GPL).

The linked patches (Niigata's site) have a readme that works fine for me.  I followed the instructions almost exactly:

1: tar -zxvf glomosim-2.03.tar.gz

2: Please move "olsr.patch" to glomosim-2.03/

3: Please type following command in glomosim-2.03/
   patch -p0 -d . < olsr.patch

1. cd glomosim/main
2. make
3. cd ../bin ; ls

You could [read the spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3626.txt), take a few weeks, and implement OLSR or it's successor.

Comment: GloMoSim is academic research version available for academic uses only. Commercial GloMoSim Based Product is QualNet. And i will very thankful to you if you give the link of OLSR code for glomosim

Comment: Nice copy and paste from Wikipedia.  While I see you are correct- the source is available - just because there is a version available for academic use does not mean the source is available.

Comment: Its not about copy and paste, i am just saying that Glomosim is well known for academic research purpose, and lesser known by priceware or commercial.